# Is there a file downloader over the tor network?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

0

Is there a console file downloader for OS Windows, over the tor network with onion resources? That is, without any intermediaries like curl+tor-bundle, wget+tor-bundle. So that this utility accepts something like:

```
tordwnl.exe -o mfqksxthtpnjhpfuhepxbrstpgjchtlybrjd.onion/document.xls -f document.xls
```

and downloaded the file to the computer disk? Or maybe the tor-bundle itself can do this, but this is not documented? It looks like here https://github.com/aberi/onion-downloader has what I need, but quite an old project and only for linux.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, **any** downloader that can use HTTPS or SOCKS5 proxy is good for the task. Also - you can run **all** the POSIX and usual tools on Windows just through [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/)

Comment: Thanks. But you didn't read the question carefully. Interested in the downloader, which contains tor-bundle in its composition

Comment: What is the exact task? OS + scenario? I'll be happy to help you - so help me to help you

Comment: Objective: to periodically download different documents. The provider's policy is such that all file-sharing networks are blocked, which is only possible, except for tor.
OS: windows.
Scenario: from one specific link, people download the file needed for a specific program. XLS file extension. But in this case, it doesn't matter.
It is important precisely through the torus and precisely without cumbersome pronouns.
So that this downloader could be sent by mail or a USB flash drive. In this case, size matters.
Here's a difficult scenario ..

Comment: Then install MSYS2 and use wget/fetch with Tor as the SOCKS/HTTPS proxy - will work exactly like in Unix/Linux and with the minimal effort and footprint posiible: environment vars like HTTP_PROXY=https://127.0.0.1:8080/ will do the job for you for Tor's internal HTTPS on 8080 and DNS on 53 on a localhost. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if there exists a standalone program that has tor client baked in - so that you wouldn't need a separate tor process running?

Such a program would have to initiate its connection to Tor network every time it's started, which would be extremely slow and costly. That is, unless it would run as a daemon, but then it would act like a system tor process anyway.

The project you linked also seems (in its own words) like "a poor man's GNU Wget". It doesn't currently do what its name says and as far as I can see it doesn't even support proxies.

I know that's not the answer you were looking for, but I recommend just using any "downloader" that supports SOCKS proxies with remote hostname resolving. You can tell such a program to connect over Tor, which also allows it to download files from .onion websites. In most cases tor proxy is specified with the following string:

```
socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050
```

The `h` in `socks5h://` tell the program that it should remotely resolve domain names. `9050` is default SOCKS port of system tor, while Tor Browser uses `9150` by default instead.

You can also tell tor process to isolate your downloader's stream via SOCKS credentials (username and password) which can be anything you want. For example:

```
socks5h://my_downloader:random_token@127.0.0.1:9050
```

This is the way Tor Browser does stream isolation based on URL-bar domain.

I've also come across programs that only recognize `socks5://` proxies (without `h`), yet internally still resolve domain names through the proxy (so no DNS leaks). youtube-dl is such an example.

If the program doesn't support SOCKS proxies then you can still try torifying it with torsocks, but if the program somehow bypasses its wrapper then it will leak. torsocks also supports stream isolation via `--isolate` argument:

```
torsocks --isolate my_downloader ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But I hope someone will suggest a solution to the problem I described. Tor has been around for quite some time, but no one has dealt with this issue.